# Infer dependencies in Gradle subproject from its parent project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge, minecraft-fabric

I currently have 3 subprojects in my Gradle project, structured like so:

```
Main Project
| 
-- Project A
-- Project B
-- Common Src
```

Project A has dependency on Lib A and Common Src, and Project B has dependency on Lib B and Common Src. Lib A and Lib B contain different implementations of the same classes.

My plan for Common Src project was to house all of the utility classes, necessarily depending on both Lib A and Lib B.

Is there a way to set this up, and how should my gradle project look like?

### Things that I've tried:

1. I've tried to remove Common Src as a subproject and just include it in the sourceSets of Project A and Project B. However, IntelliJ seems to mark Common Src as sources root of Project A, and even though build-through-gradle works, I cannot get IntelliJ to recognize that Project B also has sources root in Common Src.
2. Add both Lib A and Lib B to dependency of Common Src, but obviously that doesn't work.

### The background:

I've created a Minecraft mod compatible with both Forge (Project A) and Fabric (Project B) modloaders. I have utility classes in both projects that have the same **source code** but need to be compiled twice, each time with a different dependency. I don't want to have to write the code twice each time I want to change something in the Utility classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I've found a workaround:

1. In both `Project A` and `Project B`, add a task in each of their `build.gradle` to copy the source files from `Common Src` to the build directory of each project.
2. Configure `sourceSets` of both `Project A` and `Project B` to include source files from the build folder we just copied into
3. Configure `Common Src` to be a gradle subproject, and add `Lib A` (or `Lib B`) to the dependencies of `Common Src` (just to get IntelliJ some context)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

In the "shared" project (/module) build script, use "**api**" instead of "**implementation**" for every dependency you want your subprojects to inherit from. Example: (kotlin DSL)

```
dependencies {
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.6.4")
    ...
}
```

Then, make Project A and Project B "inherit" from that shared project like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":shared")) // "shared" is your "utility" prject
}
```